# Simulating rolling two dice java and see if the results are `1,1`

Tags: java

This is my homework problem, in Java:
Write a program that simulates rolling 2 dice 20 times.  The program outputs each pair of results and computes and outputs the number of times the result was `1, 1`.

I've tried to run this code, but I'm running into issues. This is my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int dice1, dice2, i, j, countOneOne;
countOneOne = 0;
// dice1 = 0;
// dice2 = 0;

for (j = 1;j <= 5; j++) {
    dice1 = 1 +(int) (Math.random() * 6); 
    j = dice1;
    System.out.println("Result of dice1: " + dice1);
} 
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    dice2 = 1 +(int)(Math.random()*6);
    i = dice2;
    System.out.println("Result of dice2: " + dice2);
}

System.out.println("Result of dice1: " + dice1 + " ; Result of dice2: " + die2);   

if (dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1) countOneOne++;

System.out.println(countOneOne + " is the number of 1, 1 results");
```

Firstly, it keeps telling me that I have to initialize `dice1` and `dice2` and I don't understand why. But more importantly, I know that this can't be correct, but I'm just not sure how to write a code that simultaneously rolls the two dice and then counts when they are both 1 at the same time.

Also, I tried to put them both in the same for a loop. Is this possible?

Comment: A side note: In "real" code, I basically **never** use `Math.random`. The reason is: It's not predictable. Yeah, that sounds like it was intentional, but for testing and debugging, reproducability of results etc., predictable behavior is essential. Instead, you should use [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html): Create one instance `Random random = new Random(0);` in the beginning, and use that. It also has a method that directly gives you an integer: `int dice = random.nextInt(6) + 1`.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is off a little bit, when using `Math.random() * 6` you will get a value in the range `0` to `5` inclusive (you need to add one). Also, the logic is much simpler if you extract the logic for rolling a die to a method. Something like,

```
public static int rollDie(int sides) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * sides) + 1;
}
```

Then you want to implement your method. Loop twenty times, roll two die. Count the number of snake eyes and print the roll results. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int snakeEyes = 0;
    // Twenty times
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // Roll two dice
        int die1 = rollDie(6), die2 = rollDie(6);

        // Count snake eyes.
        if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
            snakeEyes++;
        }

        // Display roll results.
        System.out.printf("Result of die1: %d ; Result of die2: %d%n", die1, die2);
    }
    System.out.printf("%d is the number of 1,1 results%n", snakeEyes);
}
```

Comment: Uhh, you beat me to the answer. Was just about to post. Well, upvoted because it works :)